# C# Best way to create folder-structures

Tags: c#, directory, directory-structure

I'd like to automatically generate diffrent folder structures (As a preperation for new Video/Film-Editing projects). It also allows to add special folders like After Effects and Photoshop to every folder-structure.

It should read the structure from a config file and then create the folders.

My current code looks like this:

```
 if(tbPath.Text == "_______________________________________________________"
            || tbConfigPath.Text == "_______________________________________________________"
            || tbPath.Text == ""
            || tbConfigPath.Text == "")
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("You didn't enter a valid Path.", "Invalid Path", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }



        //List for the paths
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();
        List<string> finalpaths = new List<string>();
        string outPath = tbPath.Text;

        //Where to get the config from
        string configPath = tbConfigPath.Text;


        string line = "";
        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(configPath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            paths.Add(line);
        }

        file.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count(); i++)
        {
            finalpaths.Add(outPath + paths[i]);
        }

        //----------------Folder Generatring------------
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count(); i++)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(finalpaths[i]);
        }


        // Add After Effects
        if (cbAE.IsChecked == true)
            {
            string AEpath = outPath + "\\AfterEffects";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AEpath);
        }

        // Add Photoshop
        if (cbAE.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string PSpath = outPath + "\\Photoshop";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PSpath);
        }


        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("The folders where generated successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

        pgStartUp pgStart = new pgStartUp();
        NavigationService.Navigate(pgStart);
```

But I feel like this isn't really efficient. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 7):

When you use:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

This line creates all or missing directories in the **path string** you are passing as a parameter. So you don't need anything else.

All your logic should be focused on creating a **correct path string**, taking into account the root directory and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

As coders we often think in code and try to solve everything with it.
If the base structure is the same, create the folder structure once, zip it up, and then:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(tbPath.Text);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("yadayada.zip", tbPath.Text);

        // Add After Effects
        if (cbAE.IsChecked == true)
            {
            string AEpath = outPath + "\\AfterEffects";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AEpath);
        }

        // Add Photoshop
        if (cbAE.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string PSpath = outPath + "\\Photoshop";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PSpath);
        }
```